# Is there a way to search for the contents in a dictionary in another dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Writing a program that searches through a file, containing names and addresses, and based on the user input takes certain names from the file and stores it in a dictionary and then the program reads another file, containing names and salaries, and stores the entire file in a dictionary. That part of the program seems to work fine but I need the program to search for the names in the first dictionary in the second dictionary but I am struggling to figure that part out and done a lot of research on it but have found nothing that solves my problem.

Comment: Why aren't you using a database?

Comment: What's the purpose of saving the city in `name_dict`? You never use it later.

Comment: Why are you using context managers to handle file objects only part of the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop can check whether `name` is in `name_dict` before adding the element to `salary_dict`.

```
for sal in sal_file:
    (name, salary) = sal.strip().split('|')
    if name in name_dict:
        salary_dict[name] = salary
```

Then you can just write everything in `salary_dict` to the new file. You could even do that in the second loop, instead of creating the dictionary.

You should use `strip()` to remove the newline from the line before splitting it. And there's no need to use `str(name)`, since `name` is already a string.